# TwitterのOAuth認証でアクセストークンが取得できない

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

グーグルスプレッドシートでTwitterのアプリを開発しているのですが、TwitterのOAuth認証の部分でアクセストークンを取得の部分でtokenがとれなく困っています。

JavaScriptでいうlocalStorage機能みたいなものはないでしょうか？

コードはこちらです

```
function getToken(){
  var acount
  var oath_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?force_login=true&screen_name="+acount;
  var access_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
  var request_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

   var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");
   var a = oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl(oath_url);
   var r =oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(access_url);
   var oa =oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl(request_url);
   var consumer = oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("twitterConsumerKey"));
   var secret = oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("twitterConsumerSecret"));
```

Comment: `localStorage` について書かれていますが、トークンを保存できないことが問題なのでしょうか。それともトークンの取得ができないのでしょうか。

Comment: トークンの取得ができておりません。

Comment: わかりました。そのコードを書かれるにあたり参考にされたサイトなど、もしあれば質問に追記していただけないでしょうか？

Comment: http://code-copilot.sacred-field.com/archive/?id=72
こちらを参考に書いております。

Answer (score 2):

- 指定する URL の組み合わせが間違っています
- `oAuthConfig.set**` は設定するだけのメソッドなので、値を返しません
- 基本的にアクセストークンは GoogleApps で管理されるので、アクセストークンの取得や保存は自分で書きません（初回は自動的にアクセス許可を求められますし、それ以降は GoogleApps で保存されたものが自動的に使われます）

という点を元に修正するとこんな感じかと。

```
function test() {
  // TwitterのOAuth設定
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

  // ConsumerKey/Secretは「スクリプトのプロパティ」から取得
  // ScriptPropertiesは非推奨になったので、PropertiesServiceを使う
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(props.getProperty("twitterConsumerKey"));
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(props.getProperty("twitterConsumerSecret"));

  var options = {
    'oAuthServiceName': 'twitter', // addOAuthServiceに指定した値
    'oAuthUseToken': 'always'
  };

  var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Twitter にアプリを登録する際、CallbackURL を `https://script.google.com/macros` とするのを忘れずに（私はここではまりました）。

### 参考サイト

- [Tutorial: Twitter Approval Manager - Apps Script — Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial)
- [Twitter検索の結果をGoogle Driveのスプレッドシートに出力する - hika69 blog](http://blog.hika69.com/blog/2014/01/28/google-apps-script/)